# Is it possible to handle or receive SES Bounce/Complaints through the AWS PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS SES with PHP SDK to send emails with attachments to customers, some of them provide an invalid email causing SES to complaint or bounce. I would like to find out what emails have failed and do a follow up by inactivating that item, calling the customer to provide a valid email or any other solution.

Is it posible to get bounce or complaints in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  But you really should be validating email addresses before you ever attempt to do anything with it.

You create an SNS topic, and add one (or more) subscriptions.  There are a number of different options when creating a subscription, but you probably want to use https.  You can have multiple subscriptions, so put your email address in there too so you can see what information is coming in.

Then, in SES, set up your SNS topic to handle bounces and/or complaints.

The AWS PHP toolkit has code and examples to handle bounces & complaints - it's pretty simple.  You'll also need to implement a validation method - SNS won't start sending data to your endpoint until it has been validated.

Comment: So and can I suscribe email(s) through the SES SDK to a SNS Topic, and if this is right can I Also view bounce/complaints through JSON? how can I do this?

Comment: You can use an email address as an SNS topic endpoint, but that would be your email address, not your customers' email addresses.  The email will contain json with attempted email, why it bounced, etc.  That same json document would be delivered to your https endpoint, parsed by the AWS PHP SDK, and the rest is up to you.

Comment: Finally did it, it´s kind of tricky because you must configure your Api so that the will call it and send the confirmation url as well as further messages, thaks for the feedback bro.